# Windows: Is a symlink to NUL (or \\.\Device\Null) possible?

Tags: windows, ntfs, symbolic-link

I have an application at hand, which insists on writing huge amounts of log lines into a file, that I have to clean out manually all the time.

Is it possible to somehow replace the file with a symlink to NUL or similar, so that any data written to the file is redirected to nirvana immediately?

I already tried with `mklink <logfile> NUL`, `mklink <logfile> NUL:`, `mklink <logfile> \\?\NUL` et al., but while this works, a (hard to delete) NUL file is created in the directory (for `NUL`) or results in an error message (for `NUL:`), as soon as the application starts to log anything to the symbolic link. So, symlinking to `NUL` (or `NUL:`) does not seem to do the job, at least not with the means I came up with.

Any ideas on a solution?

Comment: What happens if you symlink it to `\??\Nul`? The `mklink` will succeed, but IO on it will fail; is the program alright with that?

Comment: What is `\??\Nul`? This syntax is unknown to me.

Comment: It's an NT device name. [See this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/235128) for more info.

Comment: I doubt that. The correct syntax for accessing files and devices directly is different: See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Whoops, right, they're MS-DOS device names.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make a folder always empty](https://superuser.com/q/1436897/52365)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `NUL:` rather than those variants you were trying. This will work, on Windows 10 for me, at least, for a file named `c:\bob.log`:

```
mklink C:\bob.log NUL:
```

Note you do need to run this "as admin", and also the file needs to be deleted first.

Comment: Sadly, this does not do what I intended, either: The symlink is created (even without admin rights enabled), but piping anything into that file still results in an error message. Might it be that this is just not possible?

Comment: The filesystem as exposed by most of the Win32 API, including common user-facing things like explorer.exe and cmd.exe is not what's really underneath the hood.  The real "filesystem" in Windows is the "object namespace" (check out SysInternals WinObj to browse it).  Applications via various system DLLs can access things like \\?\Device\Null but that's not exposed by most built-in stuff in Windows.

Comment: For folders add the `/D` flag like this: `mklink /D c:\path\to\dir NUL:`