# Make a folder always empty

Tags: windows

There's a folder on my computer that always fills up with large amounts of junk logs, is there a way to passively empty the folder all the time? Preferably without writes ever being made to the drive.

Comment: What application is making the logs? Search online for disabling logging in that application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first choice would be to disable logging in the application creating the logs. If not, then you can create a symbolic link between the log's folder and the null directory of your operating system. Essentially this will send everything in the folder into a black hole never to be seen again.

**Windows**

Open a command prompt as administrator and run

`mklink /D c:\path\to\dir NUL:`

1. `mklink` is the command to create a symbolic link.
2. `/D` means it will be a directory
3. **Change `c:\path\to\dir` to be the path to your log directory**
4. The second path (`NUL:`) is to the NULL directory of windows (which you don't have to change)

**Linux or Mac**

Open a terminal (I don't think admin is required) and run

`ln -s /dev/null path/to/your/log/dir`

1. `ln` is used to create a link
2. `-s` means symbolic
3. `/dev/null` is the NULL directory on linux
4. **Change `path/to/your/log/dir` to be the path to your log directory.** Notice that the order of the paths are backwards for linux and Windows.

Comment: What about Mac?

Comment: Same as Linux, edited that in

Comment: /dev/null is a file, not a directory. While this will definitely keep programs from writing logs, it will cause an error inside the program instead of silently discarding them.

Comment: @SyntaxVoid Ty, I don't use mac but I know people who do